# setting display of select in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, select, default-value, display

I am trying to set the display of select tag to a value obtained through another call. But I am not able to do so even after trying [selected] ,[ngValue],[value],etc.

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedRegion" name="Region" (ngModelChange)="onRegionChange(selectedRegion)" val="true" id="cloud-region" >
                        <option *ngFor="let region of regions"  [selected]="selectedRegion.Name===region.Name?'region.Name':null">{{region.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

I set the value of "selectedRegion" after obtaining data through a http response in an Observable. I basically want to display the region that is received in another call as the selected display of select out of a pre-decided array which also contains this value.

Tried it in this plunker. Couldn't do it.
https://plnkr.co/edit/njGlIV?p=preview

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a **[value]** attribute on your `<option>`

```html
<select 
  class="form-control" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedRegion" name="Region"
  (ngModelChange)="onRegionChange(selectedRegion)"
  val="true" 
  id="cloud-region">
  
  <option 
  *ngFor="let region of regions"
  [value]="region.Name"
  [selected]="selectedRegion.Name===region.Name?'region.Name':null">{{region.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

I don't think selected is actually needed if you've already tied up your select element with a model. The reason why your select isn't reflecting because your options have no value.

UPDATED:

Based on your plunkr, I've added a simulated http call to retrieve a value from an Observable. Once i've received a value from the stream, I immediately updated my model.

```js
//our root app component
import {Component, Directive, Output, EventEmitter, Input, SimpleChange} from 'angular2/core'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
//import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>Selecting Number</h1>
    <select type="number" [(ngModel)]="levelNum" (ngModelChange)="toNumber()">
      <option *ngFor="let level of levels" [ngValue]="level.num">{{level.name}}</option>
    </select>
    {{levelNum}}
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  levelNum:number = 0;
  levels:Array<Object> = [
      {num: 0, name: "AA"},
      {num: 1, name: "BB"}
  ];
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.fakeHttpCall()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.levelNum = res;
    });
  }

  toNumber(){
    this.levelNum = +this.levelNum;
    console.log(this.levelNum);
  }
  
  fakeHttpCall(){
    let request = new Observable(
      obs => {
        let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          obs.next(1);
          obs.complete();
          clearTimeout(timeout);
        },2000);
      }  
    );
    
    return request;
  }
}
```

Comment: On trying it it displays value but not the one reflected in selectedRegion.Name but another one in the array of Objects. Could you show it by editing the above plunker to display the second one in the option as the display by setting it's value in the component? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SandeepBhat Please refer to my update, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Add [ngValue]="region.name" in your option tag. value only takes type string, you need NgValue to handle complex values such as objects.